# Access violation on recursive function with interfaces

Tags: delphi, recursion, interface, access-violation

I'm trying to resolve this problem. It's weird because it doesn't throw a Stack Overflow error but an Access Violation error. (See code below.)

Whenever `CallDestructor` function is called, `DestroyChildren` is called. So it's a recursive function.

When I'm handling only a few objects it works fine. My trouble is when I have a lot of instances to destroy.

```
unit AggregationObject;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.Generics.Collections, System.Contnrs;

type
  IParentObject = Interface;

  IChildObject = Interface
    ['{061A8518-0B3A-4A1C-AA3A-4F42B81FB4B5}']
    procedure CallDestructor();
    procedure ChangeParent(Parent: IParentObject);
  End;

  IParentObject = Interface
    ['{86162E3B-6A82-4198-AD5B-77C4623481CB}']
    procedure AddChild(ChildObject: IChildObject);
    function  RemoveChild(ChildObject: IChildObject): Integer;
    function  ChildrenCount(): Integer;
    procedure DestroyChildren();
  End;

  TName = type String;
  TChildObject = class(TInterfacedPersistent, IChildObject)
    protected
      FParentObject: IParentObject;
    public
      constructor Create( AParent: IParentObject ); virtual;

      {IChildObject}
      procedure CallDestructor();
      procedure ChangeParent(Parent: IParentObject);
  end;

  TParentObject = class(TInterfacedPersistent, IParentObject)
    strict private
      FChildren: TInterfaceList;
    private
      FName: TName;
    public
      constructor Create();

      {Polimórficos}
      procedure BeforeDestruction; override;

      {IParentObject}
      procedure AddChild(AChildObject: IChildObject);
      function  RemoveChild(AChildObject: IChildObject): Integer;
      function  ChildrenCount(): Integer;
      procedure DestroyChildren();

      property Name: TName read FName write FName;
  end;

  TAggregationObject = class(TChildObject, IParentObject)
    private
      FController: IParentObject;
      function GetController: IParentObject;
    public
      constructor Create( AParent: IParentObject ); override;
      destructor Destroy(); override;

    {Controller implementation}
    public
      property Controller: IParentObject read GetController implements IParentObject;
  end;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils, Exceptions;

{ TChildObject }

procedure TChildObject.CallDestructor;
begin
  Self.Free;
end;

procedure TChildObject.ChangeParent(Parent: IParentObject);
begin
  if Self.FParentObject <> nil then
    IParentObject( Self.FParentObject ).RemoveChild( Self );

  Self.FParentObject := Parent;
  if Parent <> nil then
    Parent.AddChild( Self );
end;

constructor TChildObject.Create(AParent: IParentObject);
begin
  if not (AParent = nil) then
  begin
    FParentObject := AParent;
    FParentObject.AddChild( Self );
  end;
end;

{ TParentObject }

procedure TParentObject.AddChild(AChildObject: IChildObject);
begin
  if (FChildren = nil) then FChildren := TInterfaceList.Create();
    FChildren.Add( AChildObject );
end;

procedure TParentObject.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  inherited;
  DestroyChildren();
end;

function TParentObject.ChildrenCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := -1;
  if Assigned(FChildren) then
    Result := FChildren.Count;
end;

constructor TParentObject.Create;
begin
  FName := 'NoName';
end;

procedure TParentObject.DestroyChildren;
var
  Instance: IChildObject;
begin
  while FChildren <> nil do
  begin
    Instance := FChildren.Last as IChildObject;
    if Instance <> nil then
    begin
      if RemoveChild( Instance ) > -1 then
      begin
        try
          Instance.CallDestructor();
        except on E: Exception do
          raise EChildAlReadyDestroyed.Create('Parent: ' + Self.FName + #13#10 + E.Message);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TParentObject.RemoveChild(AChildObject: IChildObject): Integer;
begin
  Result := -1;{if has no children}
  if (FChildren <> nil) then
  begin

    Result := 0;{ Index 0}
    if ( ( FChildren.Items[0] as IChildObject) = AChildObject) then
      FChildren.Delete(0)
    else
      Result := FChildren.RemoveItem( AChildObject, TList.TDirection.FromEnd );

    if (FChildren.Count = 0) then
    begin
      FreeAndNil( FChildren );
    end;
  end;
end;

{ TAggregationObject }

constructor TAggregationObject.Create(AParent: IParentObject);
begin
  inherited Create(AParent);
  FController := TParentObject.Create();
  ( FController as TParentObject ).Name := Self.ClassName + '_Parent';
end;

destructor TAggregationObject.Destroy;
begin
  ( FController as TParentObject ).Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TAggregationObject.GetController: IParentObject;
begin
  Result := FController;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Where does FChildren get set to nil? - it must be somewhere or else your loop would not terminate. Is FChildren.Last guaranteed to always be non-NIL? Where does the exception occur, exactly?

Comment: FChildren is set to nil when RemoveChild is called, so if FChildren.Count is equals to 0 then FChildren is set to nil. Exception occurs when CallDestructor is called but not from the first time, it occurs when a long stack is created.

Comment: FChildren.Last always need to return not nil, because when the last one in list is called, the list is set to nil and so it exits from while loop. But if not nil, a comparition to nil is made and nothing is done.

Comment: I don't know it it's a memory corruption with TInterfaceList when i put a lot of itens or if it's a stackoverflow, because the error occured is access violation and not stackoverflow

Comment: The error location suggests that RemoveChild somehow trashes the Instance instance when this happens.

Comment: Yes, it's a posibility. But how? And how can I prevent it?

Comment: You would need to post the source for RemoveChild if you want us to speculate.

Comment: Add full fastmm debug mode and try again.

Comment: Updated with RemoveChild function

Comment: I'm more interested in what's going on inside `CallDestructor`. So far, all we know is that it calls `DestroyChildren`... What else does it do?

Comment: We're still not seeing closure of the recursion loop.... I'd like offer a tip: recursion can be tricky at the best of times. You've got too many levels of indirection, making it difficult to follow and very easy to make mistakes.

Comment: Dude, when Destructor method is called, BeforeDestructionMethod is called and delegates DestroyChildren()

Comment: "Dude", you're asking for **our** help because **you** haven't been able to solve it yourself .... very possibly because you're focusing your attention in the wrong place. If your opinion on whether the full call chain is relevant were 100% reliable - you would **not need our** help!

Comment: PS: I give up **my free time** to help people like yourself. I have no desire to argue with you just to get sufficient information to solve **your** problem.

Comment: Craig Young, i do not know what bothered you. I'm here asking for help from those who are open to it. It is not necessary that you make offense, just help if you can. I'm looking for help and I thank everyone who gave their attention, and also to you. If something upset you, I apologize, but what you said is not necessary.

Comment: Updated - FastMM4_log on description.

Comment: @Lucas I didn't take offense . You are refusing to provide the code that might be crucial to solving your problem. As a result, it's unlikely anyone here will be able to help you. Note also: it appears you are using "fake" code to ask your question (your `RemoveChild` method takes `AChildObject` parameter but uses `ChildObject` without `A` prefix). I.e. it seems you retyped your code instead of copy/pasting it. As a result, it's **VERY POSSIBLE** the mistake you made in your original code has not been replicated here.... making it absolutely ***impossible*** for anyone to help.

Comment: Very hard to make sense of this code. Can you make an SSCCE? Why call DisposeOf? Doesn't look like you run on ARC. That exception swallower cannot be right. That's not the way to do anything.

Comment: I'm going to post my code as an attachment, so it's gonna be more understandable. That is the clear code, my real unit with declared classes.

Comment: Link for detailed files:[CLICK HERE](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4FEE1123CC06E702!1473&authkey=!AIsQzP-lQyxCjQU&ithint=folder%2c.txt)

Comment: PS: this error only occur when a lot of itens is created as a child. Almost all my objects inherits from TAggregationObject(TChildObject inheritance). For IParentObject implementation in TAggregationObject is not needed to be a [weak] reference once there's no refcounting.

Comment: This sounds eeriely familiar. Before I started using datasnap to make a REST server, I created my own implementation of a REST server. As part of the routing algoritm I created thousands of objects in a tree structure. This went fine as long as I only created a limited amount of objects for testing, but on full tests where thousands of objects were created and accessed from multiple threads, when the tree needed to be free'd I got unexplainable access violations. I spent weeks trying to debug this but could not find a bug in my code.

Comment: I've changed my structure. I thing the problem was with mixing object reference and interface. Even my objects isn't controlled by RefCount something hapens backstage: "However, due to the nature of interface references, _AddRef and _Release are still going to be called when the reference goes out of scope. If the class has been freed prior to that time, then you have an AV in _IntfClear." My last call in stack is _IntfClear or _IntfCopy. I think this is the problem. I'm not sure about how to correct that, so I've changed to an abstract class. Tks, @AndersE.Andersen

Comment: By now I can not spend time looking for the answer, but I will find and share with you.

Comment: @Lucas You found the exact cause of your problem. Feel free to post a self-answer for the benefit of others in your situation. I'll post an explanation of why you only sometimes get the AV. I've also edited your question for clarity, and included your exact code in the question. (I only deleted the redundant methods that did nothing other than call inherited.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The detail was the difference.

TValueObject is a specialization of TAggregationObject and it implements IMasterValue, something like this:

```
IMasterValue = interface
  //GUID Here
  function MasterValue: variant;
end;

TValueObject = class(TAggregationObject , IMasterValue)
public
  function MasterValue: variant;
end;
```

So I have:
    TSomeService = class
    public
      function Find(AMasterValue: IMasterValue): TValueObject;
    end;

```
procedure DoSome(AValueObject: TValueObject);
begin
with TSomeService.Create() do
  begin
    try
      Find(AValueObject); //This will get cleared when method exits
    finally
      AValueObject.Free(); //But the object is destroyed before that
    end;  
  end;
end;
```

//Occurs on great concurrency because the memory will be reused, otherwise the memory is still there hidding the problem. The threads running loop for destruction will show the problem.

The workaround for that, is:

```
procedure DoSome(AValueObject: TValueObject);
var
  LMasterValue: IMasterValue;
begin
  with TSomeService.Create() do
  begin
    try
      LMasterValue := AValueObject;
      try
        Find(LMasterValue);
      finally
        LMasterValue := nil;        
      end;  
    finally
      AValueObject.Free();
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

OP managed to identify the problem, but hasn't posted an answer. I provide an edited version of his comment and add a more detailed explanation.

> I think the problem was with mixing object reference and interface. Even though my objects aren't controlled by RefCount something hapens backstage: "However, due to the nature of interface references, _AddRef and _Release are still going to be called when the reference goes out of scope. If the class has been destroyed prior to that time, then you have an AV in _IntfClear." My last call in stack is _IntfClear or _IntfCopy. I think this is the problem. I'm not sure about how to correct that, so I've changed to an abstract class.

The Access Violations aren't caused by mixing object references and interfaces; there are ways to do this safely.
But they are caused by the fact that Delphi attempts to `_Release` a reference on an object that has already been destroyed.

#### However this raises the question: "Why does the AV only happen sometimes, and not all the time?"

To explain, I'm going to talk about an *illegal memory operation*. By this I mean a piece of code (or object) that accesses memory it is not supposed to.

You don't get an AV every time your program performs an *illegal memory operation*. An AV will only be raised if the *illegal memory operation* is **noticed**! There are 2 main reasons it might be unnoticed:

- It may be "illegal" for one object in your program to access certain memory, but if it **is** legal for another instance to access that memory - then there is no way for the system to notice that you've actually committed an *illegal memory operation*.
- Most of the time, FastMem requests memory from the OS in larger "pages" than what you actually request from FastMem. It then keeps track of multiple smaller allocations on the page. The page is only returned to the OS when there are no smaller allocations left on the page. Therefore again, the OS won't **notice** any *illegal memory operations* on a page still allocated to your program.

The second reason above is why a small number of objects doesn't cause an AV: The page on which the object was allocated is still allocated to your program.
But when you have a large number of instances: sometimes when you destroy an object, it the last one on a page; and the page is returned to the OS... Therefore you get AV when `_Release` is called on that page.

#### So, how do you fix it?

Well, the option you chose (use an abstract class instead of an interface) works. But you lose the benefits of interfaces. However, I would suggest **not** trying to manually control the destruction of interface objects. One of the benefits of interface references is that the underlying objects will self-destruct (*if you let them*).

I suspect you're doing this because you're mixing object references and interface references. So instead of forcing your interfaces behave like objects (and you've gone to a lot of trouble to do so), rather simply let each of your object references *manually* add a reference to the interface. You can do this with the following code:

```
(ObjectRef as IUnkown)._AddRef;
//Do stuff with ObjectRef
(ObjectRef as IUnkown)._Release;
```

**SIDE NOTE:**
You found it weird that no Stack Overflow error was raised. (And obviously you figured out why the AV was raised.) I'd like to point out that typically recursion will only trigger SO errors: if the recursion is very deep (and I mean **very**); or if each recursion allocates a rather large amount of memory on the stack.

Comment: that's a really explained answers. I thank you for your help. Based on my framework, handle it now it's gonna be a lot difficult, but I'm going to make some tests.

I really appreciate your attention.